# Enabling browser caching in wildfly 8

Tags: browser-cache, wildfly-8

How can I configure Wildfly to Leverage browser caching? I know this can be done in apache through htaccess, but how to achieve same in wildfly.
I tried to create .htaccess file and place it in both the wildfly's deployement folder and in my project directory one by one but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to add the cache control filter in the standalone.xml file.
The following link explains it all.
[Leaverage browser caching](https://gist.github.com/remibantos/5e86829e1ba6ad64eea1)